# PostgreSQL text to tsquery using pipe operators

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using PostgreSQL full-text search on a table that contains tsvectors containing Chinese words. I'm doing this with pg_jieba plugin. When I tried this

```
select plainto_tsquery('jiebaqry', '猫吃老鼠');
```

I got

```
'猫'&'吃'&'老鼠'
```

but what I want is

```
'猫'|'吃'|'老鼠'
```

How can I convert the text into a tsquery using only `|`？

P.S. In Chinese, '猫吃老鼠' means "Cats eat rats".

Comment: As far as I am aware, `plainto_tsquery` only parses the words as if all are required. There is a new function added in Postgres 11 `websearch_to_tsquery` that may be able to parse this for you https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-textsearch.html#id-1.5.8.18.8.2.2.7.1.1

Comment: Thanks Lucas. Unfortunately, I have to use PostgreSQL 9.x.